# SSD filling up; problem accessing HDD disk

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ssd

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my [MSI GV62 7RE](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GV62-7RE/Specification) laptop (no dual boot, everything wiped). I installed it to the SSD drive, but since there's not much space, I realize I will have to move some stuff to my HDD.

However, I'm unable to access my HDD. In the file manager, under the "Other Locations" tab, the disk is visible, but "locked" (encrypted). When I try to access the disk, or mount it, it simply disappears from view. When I reboot, it's again visible under the "Other Locations" tab.

I'm really new to Linux, so the solution is probably easy, but I was unable to find something that worked when googling around.

**Edit:**

Replies to some questions:

I'm no longer sure there's nothing I want to keep on the HDD. When using the "disks" app it seems to be partitioned, and one of the partitions (small, less then 1GB), and this partition is used for GRUB stuff.

However, I know there's no personal files I want to keep on this disk--I overwrote all the disks during installation, so there's nothing left anyway.

I can tell the SSD doesn't have much space from the file manager. The "Computer" disk has 35.2 GB / 123.2 GB available, and I understand this is my SSD.

The disk wasn't encrypted under windows.

Here's the result of running `sudo parted -l`, hopefully not too long:

```
Model: ATA SAMSUNG MZNLN128 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1305MB  768MB  ext4
 3      1305MB  128GB   127GB


Model: ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1305MB  768MB  ext4
 3      1305MB  1000GB  999GB


Error: /dev/mapper/luks-48fb5c79-9211-4025-b552-9dbbd107fc5d: unrecognised disk
label
Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)                                   
Disk /dev/mapper/luks-48fb5c79-9211-4025-b552-9dbbd107fc5d: 999GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1023MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0,00B  1023MB  1023MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 126GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  126GB  126GB  ext4


Error: /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: unrecognised disk label
Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)                                   
Disk /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: 127GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

I noticed some errors, but I have no idea why these occured or how to fix them.

**Edit 2:**

This is the partitions as seen through GParted. I don't understand how the HDD can be full (0.00 GB unused), but maybe that has to do with the encryption?

[GParted view of HDD (sdb)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IstXq.png)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Was it encrypted under Windows and is NTFS? Post this: `sudo parted -l` If you want to move /home see this for details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving But some like to have data partitions, but for a newer user you have to learn ownership, permissions, mounting in fstab and maybe linking folders into /home. All that is automatic with /home.

Comment: How are you determining that your SSD does not have much space? In my system, I have a 120 Gb SSD with a clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed and a few applications (LibreOffice suite etc) and I am only using a shade over 13 Gb of it. Have you run the Disks utility to give you a visual representation of what your SSD comprises?

Comment: Graham's right. Before going ahead with any changes, how about taking a look at https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/ and chart out the use of your SSD? A Gparted view of it would also be useful to add to your Question.

Answer (score 0):

When you are absolutely, positively, 101% sure there is nothing you want to save on the HDD, you can obliterate everything on it.

But you have to be REALLY sure, because, once it's gone, it's gone.

First, load [Gparted](https://gparted.org/) and look at the drives. There's a [spin box at upper right](https://gparted.org/screens/gparted-main-window.png) which will show **sda** or **sdb**

[This article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/) shows you tools you can use to analyze the use of space on your drives.

Once you are absolutely sure that you must move data to the HDD, make sure the HDD is selected in Gparted, then select each of its partitions and delete them; the [manual has specific instructions](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual).

Then, create a new partition for all of the HDD (normally **ext4** with Ubuntu), [following these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).

Then (thanks to [Jean Marie](https://askubuntu.com/users/36730/jean-marie)) copy the contents of your existing /home on the SSD into the newly created HDD, before mounting the directory on the HDD as your new /home.

Comment: before mounting it as /home I would move the content of the original /home to the newly formatted disk.